# Is there a way to load a different cacerts than the one specified in the java_home/jre/lib/security folder?

Tags: java, security, ssl, jsse

I have a single installation of java in a system that runs 2 or 3 applications.

All the applications use the same runtime.

Is there a way to specify a different keystores for the ca certs than the one in java_home/jre/lib/security. That is, is there an option to specify an "extra" keystore that is loaded and added to the certs loaded from java_home/jre/lib/security/cacerts?

What I want to avoid is having to re-import our local ca every time I upgrade the jdk in the box.

Comment: The `cacerts` file is a truststore, not a keystore. It doesn't contain any private keys.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I think you want to specify the truststore:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/gene/mycacerts ...
```

Or if you are using certs through JSSE (you probably are), you can copy your truststore to `jssecacerts` in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/` directory (although you'd still have to do that each time a JDK got installed/reinstalled). Sun's JSSE looks for `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts` before  `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`.

See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509TrustManager

Comment: Either of these _replaces_ cacerts. Q wanted to 'load[] and add[] to' which means either _copying_ cacerts to jssecacerts or /wherever/mycerts and adding the custom CA(s) to that copy, or alternatively creating a file with the custom CA(s) and then `keytool -importkeystore` the contents of cacerts into the new file.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it saved my day. I don't have the admin rights to write in C drive where I have my JDK installed. I appended "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<MyLocation>" into Tomcat Catalina and it worked.

Answer (score 22):

These both jvm options are used to locate custom truststore and their password.

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=custompath/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

In order to make sure what trustStore is being loaded by the application, add following argument as well,

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake
```

Answer (score 1):

If your JVM contains more than one application then by default all the applications will use the default cacerts store which is in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/ location .
But if you want the applications should use different cert store then you have to define the custom cert store and point to that.
In this way you can create your own certstore. 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/certStore/cusomtcacerts");-- Use this line before creating the http/https session.
You can import the certificates to the cusomtcacerts by using keytool also.

Comment: have you tested this - `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/certStore/cusomtcacerts");`

Comment: Yes. This is tested.

Answer (score -4):

According to this:

[Java SSE Referece Guide - Customization](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization)

You could use the system property:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
```

Like:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=youkeystore YourProgram
```

But!! I have never tried. Let me know if it works would you?

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer, though it is close. The javax.net.ssl.keyStore and trustStore properties are subtly different, and what the OP needs is trustStore customization.

Comment: @GregS you're probably right. Feniix, would you let us know your results? and/or what was the solution you use?

Comment: This answer is not correct. OP is asking about the truststore, not keystores.