# Certificate error while getting access token

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, google-api-java-client

I'm using the [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) to retrieve an access token.

**Code:**

```
    public static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(PATH_JSON_AUTH02))
            .createScoped(Arrays.asList(URL_SCOPE_FCM));
        googleCredential.refreshToken();
        return googleCredential.getAccessToken();
    }
```

The issue is that the JVM can't find a trusted certificate to make the HTTPS request to Google service. I tried to import all kind of Google's certificate using keytool but still not working.

**Exception:**

```
10:03:29,371 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/TesteCertificadoGoogle].[tudo.ApplicationService]] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-2) Servlet.service() for servlet tudo.ApplicationService threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Which certificate should I import?

Comment: What is the URL that your application is trying to access ? If you know the URL (maybe **PATH_JSON_AUTH02** ) you can download the certificate using the browser

Comment: The URL is in the Google API code. I think is https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth. I tried import the certificate from here before, but I will try again.

Comment: There should be no need for importing the certificate from there. I made a check and the certificate for accessing the URL: **https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth** is already presented in the Java trust store(cacerts) by default. There has to be another URL for which this error occurs

Comment: @dj_frunza you are right! We were using a custom keystore and not  the default(cacerts). As I changed to use the cacerts the request worked!! Thanks for your help. Answer the question so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I added this as an answer so that it is easier to be read by anyone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need for importing the certificate from there. I made a check and the certificate for accessing the URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth is already presented in the Java trust store(cacerts) by default. Make sure you are using the default Java trust store(cacerts)

Comment: How can I check which trust store I'm using and how can I change to use the default Java trust store?

Comment: As it can be seen in the following link, there are some JVM options that can be used to specify a different trsust store during JVM startup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642046/is-there-a-way-to-load-a-different-cacerts-than-the-one-specified-in-the-java-ho