# Does Java Runtimes require use of Keystore for SSL certificates as mandatory?

Tags: java, ssl

I would like to understand the Java runtime's requirement for SSL certificates storage in general.
I understand it can be copied to the host's /etc/ssl/certs folder but for Java, does it need to import to a specific Keystore for a runtime to be able to use and consume in any SSL verification process by the application?
E.g.
If I have a JRE client that requires packaging of a root/intermediate certificates to make web client internally to site1.foo.com, I will need the root and intermediate certificates dependent on the chain to verify the request.

With various other runtime environments, it seems I can just place them in the /etc/ssl/certs folder:
NodeJS => [How to add custom certificate authority (CA) to nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283040/how-to-add-custom-certificate-authority-ca-to-nodejs)
Go => [Where is Golang picking up root CAs from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051213/where-is-golang-picking-up-root-cas-from)

However, presumably for usage in Java, I need to go an extra step and use keytool and import into a specific Keystore?
Presumably, it can't just pick up from a common directory as per above?
Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Yes. Java requires a keystore. Several different formats are supported including PKCS#12.

Comment: Java doesn't depend on the OS for certificate handling, it has its own list of certified root certificates. They are stored in a file named `cacerts` in the `JRE_HOME/lib/security` folder.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, collections of certificates are usually accessed through a [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html) interface.

As remarked in the comments the **default** [`SSLContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) will read the certificates from a PKCS12 (or JKS) file located in `$JRE_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`.

However that is **not** the only possibility and you don't have to call `keytool` to add trusted certificates:

- on Debianoids you can use `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2642046/11748454)) to use the the PKCS12 file provided by the [`ca-certificates-java`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ca-certificates-java) package. It is updated whenever you call [`update-ca-certificates`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ca-certificates/update-ca-certificates.8.en.html). Therefore you just need to add a `*.crt` file in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and run `update-ca-certificates`.
- if you don't use the default `SSLContext` you can init it with a different `TrustManager` (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26629205/11748454)). That's how Tomcat 8.5+ loads certificates in PEM format.

Unfortunately there is no implementation of `KeyStore` that reads certificates from a directory, but that can easily be written.

**Edit:** On Debianoids the packaged JREs already use `/etc/ssl/java/cacerts`, so no further configuration is needed.